# Rails: saving from a multiple select tag into a has_many_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a select tag in multiple mode, and want my controller update action to save the multiple entries in to a has_many_and_belongs_to_many association table. How should my controller update action look, I presume I have to loop through the incoming param?

Current controller code:

```
def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = 'Your profile has been updated'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about this answer, but I will give a try.

Your controller is good enough, I suppose you are setting `@user` elsewhere.

What you need is to:

## Properly name your select

Or generate it with helpers properly named

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.collection_select :association_ids, Association.all, :id, :name, nil, multiple: ""
```

## Allow access to write `association_ids` in your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :association_ids
  ...
end
```

Comment: go rails! thanks. used this line in the end: = f.collection_select :association_ids, Association.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @user.association_ids}, {multiple: true}